# Having Issues Invoking Actions Of Controller On Button Click

Tags: php, forms, yii, gii

I'm having a problem calling an action in a controller upon button click. So the controller is generated by `Gii`. All of its actions are the default ones generated by Gii, except for the `actionCreate().`

Here is the relevant code ::

```
class ProductsController extends Controller {
 public function actionCreate() {
        $model = new Products;



      if (isset($_POST['params'])) {
        //  $model->attributes = $_POST['Products'];
        //if ($model->save())
         //   $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->id));
         echo 'Yes Working';
    }

    $this->render('create', array(
        'model' => $model,
    ));
}
```

As its clear from the above code snippet this action is calling the view named create.php.
Here is create.php::

```
<div class="page">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <h2>Create Products</h2>

    <?php echo $this->renderPartial('_form', array('model' => $model)); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the partially rendered form.

```
<?php
$form = $this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbActiveForm', array(
    'id' => 'products-form',
    'action' => Yii::app()->createUrl('products/create'),
    'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
        ));
?>

<div class="form-actions">
    <?php
    echo CHtml::submitButton('Create', array(
        'submit' => 'EasyAesthetics/index.php/products/create',
        'params' => '1'
    ));
    ?>
</div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

Now what I want is that upon clicking the button 'Create', it would call the `actionCreate()` method in the `ProductsController`. Right now the button is working and I'm being redirected to /demoProject/index.php/products/create, but the echo 'Yes Working' is not displaying.

Can anyone please show me how to achieve this. How can i invoke the create action again with just a button and just a 1 in the `$_POST` array.

I need to do this so that on clicking create the `actionCreate()` method will call the relevant components to create the necessary products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the code generated by your form. When you have model called "Hello" with a field called "world", your form field will be

```
<input type="text" name="Hello[world]">
```

Try to change your action in this way:

```
class ProductsController extends Controller {
    public function actionCreate() {
        $model = new Products;
        if (isset($_POST['Products'])) {
            echo 'Yes Working';
        }
        $this->render('create', array(
            'model' => $model,
        ));
    }
}
```

Pay particular attention to these two lines:

```
        $model = new Products;
        if (isset($_POST['Products'])) {
```

Fields will takes the same name of model. In case of more models:

```
<input type="text" name="Model1[field1]">
<input type="text" name="Model1[field2]">
<input type="text" name="Model21[field2]">
<input type="text" name="Model2[field2]">
```

and so on ...

Comment: Thanks a lot for you reply. Its working now. Somehow i thought that the POST array would be indexed using 'params' as the key, like in an associative array. Anyways, i was wrong. Thanks, again for this. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

if your "var_dump()"ed your "$_POST" , you would see sensorario answer.

and also you can set your froms send method to post if still not sending post.

```
$form = $this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbActiveForm', array(
   'id' => 'products-form',
   'action' => Yii::app()->createUrl('products/create'),
   'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
   'method' => 'post',
 ));
```

?>

or get your parameter like this(this sets by $_REQUEST):

```
$param = Yii::app()->request->getParam('Products' , null);
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I did this previously but the data is not submitting. The check for if the POST array is set is not becoming true.

Comment: your submit button might be the problem, change its type or something.

Comment: Actually it works now. echo CHtml::submitButton('Create', array(
        'submit' => 'EasyAesthetics/index.php/products/GetData',
        'params' => '1'
    ));

Comment: the GetData() action is now being called flawlesslly.